# Cannot set row height on a gridview control

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, gridview

Here is my ASP:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
    RowStyle-CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat" 
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat"
    AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Gray" 
    RowStyle-Height="400px" 
    RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
    <RowStyle Height="400px" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BlogTitle" HeaderText="BlogTitle" 
            SortExpression="BlogTitle" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" HeaderText="Image"
            DataImageUrlFormatString="~/PlaceImages/{0}" ControlStyle-CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat"
            AlternateText="Something went wrong" 
            NullDisplayText="No picture on file" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PicText" HeaderText="PicText" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TravelDate" HeaderText="TravelDate" SortExpression="TravelDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BeginText" HeaderText="BeginText" ItemStyle-Height="10px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Caption" HeaderText="Caption" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" 
            SortExpression="Country" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndText" HeaderText="EndText" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.editPhotoGridFormat
    {
        width: 220px;
        height: 180px;
    }
```

It seems like no matter where I set height, it doesn't want to change the height of my rows. You can see that I have set the height in many places in my code, and I've tried using each one individually. Any ideas folks? All the posts on gridview row height here seem to be for Android, lol.

Comment: `RowStyle-CssClass="editPhotoGridFormat"`
Can I see the contents of this css class?

Comment: I ran the exact code you provided (with my own data source) and all the cells come out 400px tall. Run the code in your browser, and then view source. Dump that along with your css into a pastebin (or fiddle) and I will take a look.

Comment: Don't know what a pastebin is. I did check it out in IE though (I've been mainly using to Firefox) and the height does get set to 400px. So it seems like Firefox doesn't like it, which is odd, because usually it is the other way around

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome either...

Comment: You know, I bet Firefox is caching your page. Open it in firefox, hold control, and press F5. Then report back. FYI, pastebin is a pretty cool website. Same with jsfiddle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37708/discussion-between-zerkey-and-joseph)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"> <rowstyle Height="20px" /></asp:GridView>
```

OR

Mention the height value for RowStyle(& AlternateRowStyle) in your HTML source

You can do that same in code-behind

```
GridView1.RowStyle.Height = 50;
```

But my suggestion is use CSS(Best way)

```
.RowStyle {
 height: 50px;
 }
.AlternateRowStyle {
 height: 50px;
 }
```

HTML Source

```
 <asp:gridview id="GridView1" runat="server" xmlns:asp="#unknown">
  RowStyle-CssClass="RowStyle"
  AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="AlternateRowStyle">
 </asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the row height in your css?

Set this style in the `CssClass` properties for the `RowStyle` and `AlternateRowStyle` styles of your GridView:

```
.smallRow 
{
  height: 150px;
}
```